# destroying item controllers once they are out of scope(memory leakage)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having some memory leakage issues in my app. After following this blog : https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3444, I tried implementing view within each loop to clear out the item controller as follows:

```
{{#each models itemController="someController" itemViewClass="AS.AutoCleanupView"}}
     ....
{{/each}}
```

My autoCleanupView looks like :

```
AS.AutoCleanupView = Ember.View.extend({

    willDestroyElement: function () {
        //console.log("Auto cleaned : "+this.get('controller'));
        this.get('controller').destroy();
    }

});
```

Now I can see that the destroy is getting called on the controllers but just to make sure I have the controller itself pushes in some global object. The way I am doing this is having this piece of code in my initialization function :

```
initialize: function () {
    AS.collectObjects.push(this);
}.on('init'),
```

So now when I move away to some other route, I was expecting my controllers to get destroyed completely and memory reclaimed. But when I check content of AS.collectObjects, the controllers are still there but their isDestroyed property is set to true. When does the controller really gets completely flushed out of memory then?

Also what are the approaches you guys take to overcome memory leakage. I have tried using chrome profiler but its just so verbose and I really can't get to the core reasons. I do destroy all my manually created ember objects within the controller's willDestroy hook too.
Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks.
Oh btw, I forgot to mention this just happens in our beloved IE8 browser.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference to the items will prevent garbage collection from occurring.  GC only reclaims objects when they no longer are referenced by anything, and it does it when it feels like it, not immediately.

The only way to watch if an object is properly being disposed is to use an in-browser profiler.

Anecdotal statement of the day, I've got three enterprise apps using Ember and haven't noticed any sort of memory leaks, are you sure it's Ember?

Comment: Hopefully its not ember and given your example I am pretty sure its not ember, but I was having really difficult time profiling my app and figuring out what is not getting destroyed and when I saw those objects still existing in my global object I thought Ember must not be cleaning those up. I've tried using profiler, but I guess my question should have been how to figure out the profile thing. I see bunch of objects added everytime I visit in and out of same route and I cannot really figure out what those objects really are :(

Comment: But given the route I took, and given your experience could you tell me if I am following the right path and is there anything obvious that we must be doing to avoid memory leakage that you know of?

Comment: generally circular references, event listeners, scoping issues, and accidental references are where I see the most memory leaks, but that's again anecdotal. I'd read through something like https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-sieve/ and see if you can find any anti-patterns that you might be following.